# Validate HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following code;  I want to make sure that submit does not actually post to the page specified by action unless one of the two radio inputs has been selected.  I have tried multiple variations of this and other code, and cannot seem to figure out whats wrong.  Whether the radio buttons are selected or not it still posts to somepage.py.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test Page
        </title>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function validate(formEntry) {

                if (formEntry.Q1.q11.checked != true && formEntry.Q1.q12.checked != true)
                    return false;

                return true;
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="somepage.py" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="q11" value="1" />
            <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="q12" value="2" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make one selected by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make one button checked by defualt, then one will always be checked:

```
<input type="radio" name="Q1" id="q11" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="Q1" id="q12" value="2" >
```

Or the function can be simply:

```
function validate(formEntry) {
    return formEntry.Q1[0].checked || formEntry.Q1[1].checked ;
}
```

if either is checked it will return true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!formEntry.Q1[0].checked && !formEntry.Q1[1].checked)`

Trying to access input by *form_name***.***input_name***.***input_id* is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery validation. Checkout this link for details
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Demo page here:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work, look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/EEgea/

Maybe you'd better use a framework like JQuery to prevent javascript flaws between different browsers

Or use a validation framework like JQuery validation, I highly recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

try your function like :-

```
function validate(formEntry) {

   var radiobtn=document.getElementsByName('Q1');
   if(!(radiobtn[0].checked || radiobtn[1].checked))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```